# Sierra stuck at login screen - password doesn't work

Tags: macos, open-directory

This has happened to me twice in the past week.  I put my MacBook Pro to sleep while my user account is logged in.  When I return, I enter the correct password and it shakes, as if the password were wrong.  I try several times, and get nowhere.  So I force reboot, and then I am able to login again.  Here are some relevant lines from the log right after the reboot.  The opendirectory lines are repeated hundreds of times.

```
loginwindow: -[LWBuiltInScreenLockAuthLion verifyPassword] | ERROR | Verify password called with PAM auth set to YES, but pam handle == nil
opendirectoryd: Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
opendirectoryd: queuing request to connection - '<private>'
loginwindow: (libpam.2.dylib) in od_record_create(): failed: 13
loginwindow: (libpam.2.dylib) in od_record_create_cstring(): failed: 13
loginwindow: (libpam.2.dylib) in pam_sm_authenticate(): OpenDirectory - Unable to get user record.
```

This is running Sierra 10.12.6.  Filevault is disabled.  I also notice after the reboot, Spotlight is hogging CPU for several minutes, like it's rebuilding an index, but that might be a red herring, just caused by the reboot.

Comment: Check your keyboard mapping and functionning. If you can switch user, do it and check your keyboard within the user form.

Comment: Check your FS (`Disk Utility`) from an USB bootable key (with Sierra, not High Sierra).

Comment: seems the PAM authentication was not handling the login at that time,and that was most possibly the reason.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Keyboard mapping is correct, since I can type the username

Comment: @FrontENG I'm not sure what PAM is, is it normally used for macOS logins? I have never joined a domain or other active directory with this machine, just regular local accounts

Comment: Need the full log just before and after failed logging or you could create a new account and see if it works

Comment: Within the user name field, type your password without looking your screen, don’t hit return. Is it correct? Erase it (to avoid writing it in your logs).

Answer (score 1):

**Try to reset your login password at first:**

[macOS Sierra: Reset a login password](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25720?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

If the above didn't help, try to reset Nonvolatile Random-Access Memory and System Management Controller:

[How to reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

[How to reset the SMC on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

P.S. I experienced the same issue on Mac Mini with El Capital. Resetting PRAM and SMC helped me to fix it.

Comment: Any documentation as to why NVRAM or SMC would cause this specific issue?

Comment: I haven't found any official documentation on this problem.

Comment: That "macOS Sierra" link no longer works